# GWT Widget.addHandler

Tags: gwt, event-handling, addhandler

I am trying to utilize `Widget.addHandler()`. However, the handler never gets called.  Below is my sample code. What do I need to change to fix this?

My Handler Implementation:

```java
public class CustomMouseMoveHandler
  extends GwtEvent.Type<MouseMoveHandler>
  implements MouseMoveHandler
{
  @Override
  public void onMouseMove(MouseMoveEvent event) {
    System.out.println("----> onMouseMove.");
  }
}
```

My `EntryPoint.OnModuleLoad()`:

```java
ContentPanel cp = new ContentPanel();
cp.setHeaderVisible(false);
cp.setHeight(com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.getClientHeight());

CustomMouseMoveHandler handler = new CustomMouseMoveHandler();
cp.addHandler(handler, handler);

RootPanel.get().add(cp);
```

/////
Added on 7/1/2011.

The following complete GWT simple code does not work either (with Jason's hint applied).  Please help me out.  Thanks

```java
 package tut.client;

 import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
 import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.MouseMoveEvent;
 import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.MouseMoveHandler;
 import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
 import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextArea;

  /**
  * Entry point classes define <code>onModuleLoad()</code>.
  */
    public class GwtHandler implements EntryPoint, MouseMoveHandler {

        /**
         * This is the entry point method.
         */
        public void onModuleLoad() {
           TextArea comp = new TextArea();

           comp.setSize("200px", "200px");
           comp.setText("Testing Text");        

           comp.addHandler(this, MouseMoveEvent.getType());

           RootPanel.get().add(comp);
        }

       @Override
       public void onMouseMove(MouseMoveEvent event) {
           com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.alert("onMouseMove");
       }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`GwtEvent.Type` is used to dispatch events based on an event specific and unique object (object equality - `==` - is used to match event types). Passing your `CustomMouseMoveHandler` as the `Type` to `addHandler` indicates an event type other than that used for `MouseMoveEvent`s (Indeed in this case every `CustomMouseMoveHandler` would be assigned to a different event `Type` since each object is different).

Instead of extending `GwtEvent.Type<MouseMoveHandler>` in your handler you need to get the event `Type` from `MouseMoveEvent` itself (using the static `getType()` method).

Don't extend `GwtEvent.Type` in your `CustomMouseMoveHandler`:

```
public class CustomMouseMoveHandler
  implements MouseMoveHandler
{
  ...
}
```

And to add the handler:

```
cp.addDomHandler(handler, MouseMoveEvent.getType());
```

Comment: Thanks for help Jason.  It still does not work for me yet.  Please see my edited question above.

Comment: `System.out.println()` is a no-op in GWT, because there is no cross-browser "stdout" to print to. Try using something like `Window.alert()` to detect the event instead.

Comment: GWT.log() can also be used to print debug messages.

Comment: Also, Peter, please don't make edits to questions that change them fundamentally. If you, for example, change the code in the question to match an answer then those who look at the question later will be confused as to what the original problem was.

Comment: For the sake of simple to put System.out.println on my question. However, I used Log.info() in my actual code, and also set debugger break point in the Log.info() statement.  It does not jump to the statement at all.  Thanks for help Jason and Daniel!

Comment: I just realized that my edited question is rolled back to the original. According to Jason hint, I edited my code as cp.addHandler(this, MouseMoveEvent.getType());  where this implements MouseMoveListener.

Comment: Jason, combine your hint with Thomas'. It works now.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I changed addHandler to addDomHandler in my answer. Thanks Thomas.

Answer (score 5):

DomEvents have to be registered using addDomHandler, or you have to sinkEvents for their event type. addDomHandler is a shortcut for sinkEvents+addHandler.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I solved my problem. I wanted to add handlers to a **NumberLabel**. This is what worked:

```
    final NumberLabel<Long> label = new NumberLabel<Long>();
    label.setValue(2000l);
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    MouseOverHandler handler = new MouseOverHandler() {

        public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent event) {
            System.out.println("mouse over");
        }
    };
    Widget widget = label.asWidget();
    widget.addDomHandler(handler, MouseOverEvent.getType());
```

Treating is as a Widget did the trick.

By the way, `System.out.println` worked.

Comment: Struggled a lot. It worked even without converting to widget.