# How Can I Add a HandlerManager to a UI-Element in GWT?

Tags: gwt, user-interface, view, mvp

In my project I use the `Model-View-Presenter` and want to create a UI-Element where I can register a HandlerManager to handle client-side events.

How can I do something like this? Or does it not conform to MVP?

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question correctly. But for adding custom handler to UI elements refer to this stackoverflow [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537458/gwt-widget-addhandler).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you are using the UiBinder paradigm, you can specify a UiHandler, using the `@UiHandler` annotation on your method (see [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Simple_binding)).

If you have more details on exactly what you're trying to do, then I can probably provide other solutions as well.